# How to fix mongoose validator error when the required value is provided, but mongoose doesn't recognize it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm saving a document to mongoDB, but I get a validator error saying 
"ValidatorError: Path `properties.chargeBoxIdentity` is required."

I have a different document that works fine. I have copied and pasted it and modified it but this Heartbeat document just wont work.

I have tried to "hardcode" the chargeBoxIdentity value to the document, but this did not work.
I set a hardcoded default value in the schema like the date is and that did work, but this is not ideal for my use case, as each charger has a different identity.

```
const HeartbeatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    properties: {
        time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
        chargeBoxIdentity : { type: Number, required: true}
    },
    additionalProperties: false
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Heartbeat', HeartbeatSchema)


// Here I set chargeBox Identity as 12345, but I get an error that properties.chargeBoxIdentity is required and won't save the document

const HB = new HeartbeatModel({
          chargeBoxIdentity: 12345

        });

  HB.save()
        .then(result => {console.log(result)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a minor error in your syntax, change these lines into:

```
const HB = new HeartbeatModel({
          properties: {chargeBoxIdentity: 12345}
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured it out. The other document works fine for some reason, and it doesn't have the properties parameter.
Thanks again